# awk - partial match of several columns between two files and return a one liner of both files concatenated with comma

Tags: awk, partial-matches

I have two files, each one contains the following:

`/tmp/mydir-1`:

```
direction=1, code=a b c d, time=xxxx
direction=1, code=f x fdfsdf sdfs, time=xxxx
direction=1, code=a b c f, time=xxxx
```

and the 2nd file `/tmp/mydir-2`:

```
direction2=2, code2=a b c fsd, time2=xxxx
direction2=2, code2=f x fdfsdf sdfs, time2=xxxx
direction2=2, code2=a b c ff, time2=xxxx
```

i want to match in file2, only lines that contains `code2=XXX` that matches the `code=XXX` in the first file, and to return each line of both files concatenated by `,`.

which means that if here the only lines that matches between these two files are:

```
direction=1, code=f x fdfsdf sdfs, time=xxxx
```

and

```
direction2=2, code2=f x fdfsdf sdfs, time2=xxxx
```

so to return:

```
direction=1, code=f x fdfsdf sdfs, time=xxxx, direction2=2, code2=f x fdfsdf sdfs, time2=xxxx
```

I'm new to awk.. i need to do some stuff but still don't know how to connect the things together.

i know that with this i can split the code or code2 column and to print the actual value after the `=` with:

```
cat /tmp/mydir-1 |  awk -F ', ' '{split($2,aa,"="); print aa[2]}'
```

this returns:

```
a b c d
f x fdfsdf sdfs
a b c f
```

now i'm trying to split the code column by `=` and compare the value between both files and this is where i go wrong.

when I execute this:

```
awk -F ', ' 'FNR==NR {split($2,aa,"="); a[aa[2]]; next} split($2, aaa, "="); aaa[2] in a' /tmp/mydir-1 /tmp/mydir-2
```

I get tall the lines is `mydir-2` duplicated:

```
direction2=2, code2=a b c f, time2=xxxx
direction2=2, code2=a b c f, time2=xxxx
direction2=2, code2=f x fdfsdf sdfs, time2=xxxx
direction2=2, code2=f x fdfsdf sdfs, time2=xxxx
direction2=2, code2=a b c ff, time2=xxxx
```

so this is where i'm stuck. I'm guessing i'm comparing the 2nd file to itself somehow ? not really sure how to continue from here.

any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

**update**

thanks @KamilCuk for your update.

I changed the variable names and this is the command:

```
awk -F ', ' 'FNR==NR {split($2,f1split,"="); f1[f1split[2]]; next} {split($2, f2plit, "=");} f2split[2] in f1' /tmp/mydir-1 /tmp/mydir-2
```

I added the 2nd split for the 2nd file in `{}` as @KamilCuk mentioned, and when I execute it the results are empty.

the variable names and what i think they mean:

```
f1: first file
f2: 2nd file
f1split: first file 'code' split
f2split: 2nd file 'code2' split
```

did i understand awk syntax correctly in the matter of what awk code relates to the first file and what to the 2nd ?

```
awk 'FNR==NR {<CODE FOR FIRST FILE>} <CODE FOR 2nd FILE>' /tmp/mydir-1 /tmp/mydir-2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[=,]"; OFS=", " }
NR==FNR {
    file1[$4] = $0
    next
}
$4 in file1 {
    print file1[$4], $0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
direction=1, code=f x fdfsdf sdfs, time=xxxx, direction2=2, code2=f x fdfsdf sdfs, time2=xxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

`split` returns the number of elements, so it's non-zero, so it prints the line. Put it inside `{` `}`

```
awk -F ', ' '
FNR==NR{
      split($2, aa, "=");
      a[aa[2]];
      next
}
# empty non-zero expression prints the line
# put it inside { } to silence output
{ split($2, aaa, "=") }

# Use different variables names then a aa aaa....
aaa[2] in a
' /tmp/mydir-1 /tmp/mydir-2
```